# check duplicates in html table while adding table data dynamically

Tags: jquery, html-table

My table Looks like this:

```
<table style="width:100%" class="table table-striped table-bordered" id="xxxxxx">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Item Id</th>
            <th>Item Name</th>
            <th>Rate</th>
            <th>Quantity</th>
            <th>Total</th>
            <th>Edit</th>
        </tr> 
    </thead>
</table>
```

I am adding data to my table on a button click like this:

```
var item_x = $('#itemIdx').val();
var item_x_name = $('#itemx option:selected').val();
var rate_x = $('#ratex').val();
var quantity_x = $('#quantityx').val();
var total_x = rate_x * quantity_x;

var add_to_table = '<tr><td>' + item_x + '</td><td>' + item_x_name + '</td><td>' + rate_x + '</td><td>' + quantity_x + '</td><td>' + total_x + "</td><td><buttonDelete</button></td>";
$('#xxxxxx').append(add_to_table);
```

Now While adding data dynamically I want to duplicate data based on `item_x` value whether it is repeated or not. If repeated then an alert is to be shown; if not simply add to the `xxxxxx` to table.

Answer (score 2):

You can check the existence using:

```
var tdlength= $("td").filter(function() {
    return $(this).text().toLowerCase() == item_x ;//get td with item_x 
 }).length;

if(!tdlength){ //td with html item_x  does not exists.
   //code here
}
```

Comment: Thank You Milind..but i dont want any duplicates data to be added..item_x is getting populated on the change event of "item_x_name"..so if i find 2 same item_x i wont allow it to add in the table..on a button click..

Comment: You can put that if condition in click event.